# How to access a private nested class object of a sole class that uses it in java

Tags: java

I have a base class in Java. In that class I want to create a private class and I want to access the object of that private class in the base class. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "access the object of that private class" - what do you mean by this exactly? Do you want to create an instance of that private class in the parent class?

Comment: as you would any other class. Create an instance and then use that reference to access methods. You could create a static method in you inner class and you should be able to access it directly then

Comment: I see you removed the accepted answer mark. Are you still encountering problems?

Answer (score 2):

You can access an object of an inner class by creating it and remembering its reference. Just like an instance of any other class.

```
public enum Outer {;
    private static class Nested {
        private Nested() { }
    }

    public static Object getNested() {
        return new Nested();
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args)  {
        System.out.println("I have an "+ Outer.newNested());
    }
}
```

prints

```
I have an Outer$Nested@3f0ef90c
```

---

A good example is from Arrays. This creates an instance of a private nested class which implements a public interface which makes it useful.

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
return new ArrayList<T>(a);
}

/**
 * @serial include
 */
private static class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
implements RandomAccess, java.io.Serializable
{
```

Comment: +1 but the scope of private inner class is only within Outer class

Comment: @Nandkumar You can still pass it to another class once it has been created.

Comment: @Nandkumar I have changed my example. Note: even the constructor is `private` ;)

Comment: There's a semicolon floating around. :)

Comment: @Tudor Its actually required. :D See if you can work out why. ;)

Comment: You're right, it doesn't compiler without it, although I admit enums are not my strong point...

Comment: @Tudor For utility classes I use an `enum` with no instances. This makes sure there is a private constructor for you. An `enum` need a `;` between the instance names and other members.

Comment: @PeterLawrey : you returned `Object`, clever :D, I was thinking using inner private class.

Comment: @Nandkumar Normally the private class implements a public interface. e.g. `Arrays.asList()` return a private nested class which implements `List`

Comment: @Tudor - yeah, I want  to create an instance of  private nested class in the parent class.

Comment: @KabirPrince Added an example of how Arrays in the JDK does this.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this:

```
class Test {

    private Inner inner = new Inner();  

    private class Inner {
        public void foo() {}
    }

    // later somewhere
    public void bar() {
        inner.foo();
    }      
}
```

Comment: NOTE:  The difference between this example and the other answer with a "static class" is that this one allows the instance of the inner class to access variables and methods of the Test class that created it.  It has an implicit pointer to it's creating instance, accessible as: "Test.this". The "static" version cannot do that, it can only access other "static" variables and methods of the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

```
PrivateClass c = new PrivateClass();
c.getSomeObject(); //??
```

You can use the above code in your base class; provided the private class is an inner class of your base class.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test {

    private class Inner {
        public void foo() {
            System.out.println("vsahdashdashd");
        }
    }

    // later somewhere
    public void bar() {
        new Inner().foo();
    }      
}
class javaapplication9 extends Test
{
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test inner = new Test();  
        inner.bar();
      }
you can access private member from this type.
```